# Why is code beneath recursive call processed more than once (when the base case is true)?

Tags: java, recursion

First my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class recursionQuestion {

  public static void methodB(boolean b) {
    if(b == true) {
      System.out.println("'b' is true!");
    } else {
      methodA();
    }
  }

  public static void methodA() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter 0 or 1: ");
    int val = keyboard.nextInt();
    boolean b;
    if(val == 0) {
      b = false;
    } else {
      b = true;
    }
    methodB(b);
    System.out.println("Why is this being processed when b is false?");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    methodA();
  }

}
```

I always thought I understood recursion, but perhaps I do not. If the user is prompted for input and enters '0' x amount of times, why does this code print the line "Why is this being processed when b is false?" x number of times?

Put another way, why is the code (in `methodA()`) below the call to `methodB()` being processed more than once? Shouldn't the call (in `methodB()`) to `methodA()` return the flow of execution to the top of `methodA()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call  `methodB(b)` from `methodA` when b is false, it triggers a new call to `methodA`. Once the execution of that call to `methodA` and then the execution of the call to `methodB` both end, control returns to the instance of `methodA` that called `methodB`, and therefore your line is printed.

Here's a possible scenario :

```
methodA
  calls methodB(false)
    calls methodA
      calls methodB(false)
        calls methodA
          calls methodB(true)
            prints "'b' is true!" and returns
          prints "Why is this being processed when b is false?"
      prints "Why is this being processed when b is false?"
  prints "Why is this being processed when b is false?"
```

Comment: I understand now. I was using this structure of code to sanitize user input within methodA(). What would be a better way to make sure, for example, that b is true?

Comment: @gb109 a while loop would be better

Answer (score 1):

Method A calls Method B. After B is executed, control is returned to A. Hence the line being printed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what the recursive calls are doing.

```
methodA()
    methodB() [if user entered 0], then b is false
        methodA() [assume a non-zero number is entered]
            methodB()
                "'b' is true!"
        "Why is this being processed when b is false?"

"Why is this being processed when b is false?"
```

Regardless of what value you put in for your `methodB()` call, you will *always* be executing the print statement.  This is because the execution point is returned to where the call was made; in this case, it'd be *just* after the call to `methodB()`.

If printing the statement was required as a condition on your recursion, you'd be required to add that as a condition to your recursive step.  In this scenario, it's two methods more or less bouncing back and forth with each other.